# Is there a way to connect a physical mouse, keyboard, and monitor to GS4 at the same time?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, docking-station

I have seen some other questions but the answers are not helpful in my situation for various reasons. I am trying to recover contacts, pictures, etc. from someone's Galaxy S4 that they did not have backed up. The phone still powers on and has sound but the screen does not turn on and nothing can be pressed. I took the phone to AT&T but they said that they needed the screen to turn on in order to transfer. I've heard that the Samsung dock should work, but it seems that you still need the screen to work in order to use the dock. Can anyone give me ideas on how to retrieve the information from the device?

Comment: If you can, you may try a USB-OTG (on the go) adapter and  plug a USB-Hub into it. Then connect as many USB devices as you wish. Keep in mind that the hub has to have its own power adapter because the micro-USB connector does not have enough power for more than one device.

Comment: You'd first have to have adb enabled in developer settings. Then you'll be able to edit system files, to accomplish attachment of the other peripherals. But through adb you could do a dump of the system with the `dd` command and just be done with it.

Comment: @HasH_BrowN That doesn't help because USB debugging is required and USB debugging is not turned on.

Comment: That is why its a comment, and not an answer. Search through SE for enabling adb debugging with PC.

Comment: @HasH_BrowN You can't enable debugging with a PC.

Comment: Yes you can, a little research would have shown you. Here is just one of the results I found [http://igor.moomers.org/recovering-an-android-phone/](http://igor.moomers.org/recovering-an-android-phone/).

Comment: Here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326806/enable-usb-debugging-through-clockworkmod-with-adb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326806/enable-usb-debugging-through-clockworkmod-with-adb)  right here, on Stack Exchange. This was linked inside the other link I provided you.